# Why this is undefined ( using babel )

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am kinda new using javascript and I have this problem ..

In this IIFE

```
(function () {

this.something = "something"; // error - this is undefined 

let loader = PIXI.loader;
    loader.add('ace', "assets/spritesData.json");
    loader.on('complete', onAssetsLoaded);
    loader.load();


function onAssetsLoaded(){
    this.gameSettings = GameSettings.getInstance();

    createrenderer();
    let rootView = new RootView(this._stage),
        rootController = new RootController(rootView,this.gameSettings);

    animate();
}
})();
```

Why "this" is undefined ? From what I know till now "this" right now this should be the current scope of the function ( in this case the anon function ) ?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's throwing that error, but just FYI - `this` will refer to the global context (e.g. `window`) in your code, not the function context (you would need to use `new ...` instantiation to have it refer to the function)

Comment: @RobM. — It would hold the global context in non-strict mode, but Babel always operates in strict mode.

Comment: Right . Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` usually refers to the calling object, but your function is anonymous and invoked directly. Here is how you can create new contexts:

- the `new` keyword, will create a new `this` context and return it.

  ```
  function Constructor() { this.property = "a"; };
  let instance = new Constructor();
  // instance.property is now "a"
  ```
- `function.bind({})` will wrap the function so when it is invoked, `this` will refer to `{}`. `function.apply` works similarly, but immediately invokes the function and requires you to specify the arguments too.
- For advanced users: [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Answer (score 1):

The long explanation can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work). The relevant part (which isn't mentioned in the accepted answer as far as I can see) is:

> when we use strict mode, `this` holds the value of `undefined` in global functions and in anonymous functions that are not bound to any object